# MenuBar coordinates JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, menu

I created the simplest program and now I want to make a menu. The problem is that I can't change menu bar coordinates by the using method setLayoutX/setLayoutY. How can you solve this? Advice please.

```
public class ForCyber extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
    }

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {

        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();


        HBox root = new HBox();
        lineChart.getData().add(series1);

        root.getChildren().add(lineChart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 650, 330);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);


        for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(i, i));
        }

        for (XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series : lineChart.getData()) {
            for (XYChart.Data<Number, Number> data : series.getData()) {
                StackPane stackPane = (StackPane) data.getNode();
                stackPane.setVisible(false);
            }
        }

        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("Data");
        fileMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Test"));
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(fileMenu);
        menuBar.setLayoutX(123);
        menuBar.setLayoutY(400);
        root.getChildren().add(menuBar);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Either use `Pane` as parent or set the `managed` property to `false` which results in the node being ignored by the parent during layout... But why do you want to move the menu and how should this afflect the siblings during layout?

Comment: Putting a menu bar in a `HBox` seems like a strange thing to want to do. Typically you use a `BorderPane`, or at least a `VBox`. How do you actually want the different nodes to be laid out?

Comment: I just switched to BorderPane now. But now I can see only small piece of chart and menu, how to fix it? https://pastebin.com/C0F4iBSm

Comment: Is it possible to run more then one application at the same scene??